# Can logs be disabled to prevent process mining

Tags: database, process, data-mining, event-log

The foundation of process mining is event logs. I want to ask that is it possible that if someone disables logs to prevent process being mined. 
Moreover in case if someone disables it, How will process mining will work then as Event logs are base of process mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event logs in Process Mining do not directly correspond to logs of software modules. One can create event logs from information in databases, network traffic, application logs, GPS positions etc etc. And yes, if you do not have any information about events of a process you cannot do Process Mining.

Answer (score 0):

Logging is just the easiest and most reliable way of collecting such data.

You could also collect such data e.g. on client side, or by scraping, or by artifacts and communication.